# LEDs + Constant Current Driver - Discharging the Circuit

Tags: led, switch-mode-power-supply, constant-current, discharge

I have a project where I made a series of high power Osram OSLON blue leds using custom boards on aluminium PCB. I just put 16 LEDs in series and joined them to an appropriate constant current supply. They all light up well and the currrent/voltages all seems to what I expected when measured. However, when turned off the LEDs have a significant glow and the supply has a significant voltage across the circuit.

LEDS: https://uk.rs-online.com/web/p/visible-leds/1751980/

CC Supply: https://uk.rs-online.com/web/p/products/7911118

Do I need to improve my circuit so that it safely discharges?
I take it that this would mean putting a resistor somewhere?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Yes, a small "bleeding" resistor across your LED load might help. Did you try it?

Comment: "When turned off" - how turned off?

Comment: The power removed from the CC supply.

Comment: Thanks for the help! Especially because I didn't know it would be called a "bleeding resistor". Now it makes the searches much easier!

Comment: What voltage = LEDs good and what voltage did you measure when supposedly off? If you waited 5 minutes, did the LEDs eventually dim to zero perceived brightness?

Comment: I was wondering the same thing, how to "power off". The MW driver has two pins IN, and two pins OUT, yet the datasheet says "three step analog dimming". What is it?

Comment: The three step analog dimming is quite cool! Basically if you turn it on then off and on again it turns on at 1/2 power, etc.

Comment: And, to get the 10% LED current thing, what do you do?

Comment: The LEDs fade faster that 30 secs but the voltage drops from ~50V at quite a slow rate.

Comment: Cycle off and on one more time for 10%. Although that would technically put the LEDs below their minimum rated 200mA.

Comment: What would be acceptable to you?

Comment: Why does the LED data sheet say "do not use below 200 mA"? Anyone?

Comment: In computer design business (laptops) the "active bleeding" of power rails is a common thing, to avoid these long transients when turning off or in low-power mode. It is done by means of MOSFET switches and bleeding resistors. I don't know how or whether it is done in power electronics.

Comment: In terms of what would be acceptable, I don't know TBH! I'd be happy for any of your ideas :)

I actually don't know what happens when the power goes off? I assume that the current drops to zero leaving the same voltage that was used when the current was 700mA discharging from some massive capacitors.

Comment: @Andyaka, good question. LEDs usually don't care. But the drawings show some additional die on the substrate. The datasheet also talks about external ESD protection circuit on the side. Where is our power LED expert "misunderstood" when we need him?

Comment: @Andyaka, "do not use below 200 mA", which formally should also mean that you can't keep the LED in unpowered state, and therefore you can't use it at all, ironically. So there must be some details lost in translation.

Comment: It's a clue maybe? I'm out of here. Use bleeders LOL!!

Comment: Low Current operation of Indium-based LEDs (Blue,White) causes rapid defect growth due to uneven charge flow so dim intensity for current useage <10% dimishes rapidly. Fortunately cranking of the current burns off these defects so normal high current restores expected brightness

Comment: Haha! That's true! They definitely arrived with less than 200mA going them them on the tape :)

Comment: How long does it take to get below 5V?  5KOhm 1 Watt drawing 0.5W may speed it up a bit.

Comment: I will investigate and get back to you ASAP!

Comment: @TonyEErocketscientist `Low Current operation of Indium-based LEDs (Blue,White) causes rapid defect growth`  Can you add an answer with more and any references? It sounds like a fascinating aspect.

Comment: I’ll see what I can dig up

Comment: Here’s an irrelevant but interesting history on Droop which fixed over 10 yrs ago with Aluminum https://www.google.ca/amp/s/spectrum.ieee.org/semiconductors/optoelectronics/the-leds-dark-secret.amp.html

Answer (score 1):

@TonyEErocketscientist has the credit for this answer!!! Adding the bleeder resistor worked nicely! 5k Ohm, 5 W in parallel with series LED chain results in no discernible dimming of the LEDs and the voltage drops smoothly to <5V in 20 secs!!

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

The switch is not an on off switch.  It toggles between 100%, 40%, and 10% of the 700 mA output.

You have to add your own switch if you want a power on off switch.

The current Mean Well PLM-40 series do not have the dim switch.  The link is to a manual from 2013.

[Manual PLM 40 Series](https://docs-emea.rs-online.com/webdocs/1279/0900766b812790ba.pdf)

---

[image]